# Can anyone suggest me is there any possible way to add a php variable in css

Tags: php, css, web-deployment

Is it possible to add a php variable in css file ? If so how to add ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: no way, btw why would you want it

Comment: what's your actual purpose?

Comment: So you know, your question has been downvoted because it does not feature any evidence of research or prior effort. If you do some relevant searches, e.g. "[Output CSS PHP](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=output+css+php)" then you should find how to do what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP & CSS Output Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599818/php-css-output-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. First, you create `.php` file. Next, you write CSS in there and echo any needed variables

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/css");
    $color = "#ddd";
?>
#div {
    color: <?php echo $color; ?>;
}
```

Also, consider using LESS or other similar CSS framework (if possible for your needs). It allows to have variables, calculations, functions and much more.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is text. You can output it from a PHP script almost as easily as HTML.

You just need to specify the content-type because the default (HTML) is unsuitable.

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/css");
    $background = "orange";
?>

body { background: <?php echo $foo; ?>; }
```

Beware of caching issues introduced by dynamically generating CSS.